# Tailwind Components Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, daisyui, tailwind-elements

I just completed my first fresh install of Tailwind CSS and I can't seem to get some components working. I'm trying to use a Daisy UI navbar but it doesn't display correctly within my page. It almost looks like the navbar is wrapping itself. Can anybody help me find where I went wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
  <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar bg-base-100">
  <div class="navbar-start">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <label tabindex="0" class="btn btn-ghost btn-circle">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h7" /></svg>
      </label>
      <ul tabindex="0" class="menu menu-sm dropdown-content mt-3 z-[1] p-2 shadow bg-base-100 rounded-box w-52">
        <li><a>Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a>Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a>About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-center">
    <a class="btn btn-ghost normal-case text-xl">daisyUI</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-end">
    <button class="btn btn-ghost btn-circle">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z" /></svg>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-ghost btn-circle">
      <div class="indicator">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" /></svg>
        <span class="badge badge-xs badge-primary indicator-item"></span>
      </div>
    </button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FnuB.png)

I installed the daisy UI and added this to my tailwind.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
      // using ./src/ dir
    "./src/*.{html,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    // using ./ dir
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
  // daisyUI config (optional - here are the default values)
  daisyui: {
    themes: false, // true: all themes | false: only light + dark | array: specific themes like this ["light", "dark", "cupcake"]
    darkTheme: "dark", // name of one of the included themes for dark mode
    base: true, // applies background color and foreground color for root element by default
    styled: true, // include daisyUI colors and design decisions for all components
    utils: true, // adds responsive and modifier utility classes
    rtl: false, // rotate style direction from left-to-right to right-to-left. You also need to add dir="rtl" to your html tag and install `tailwindcss-flip` plugin for Tailwind CSS.
    prefix: "", // prefix for daisyUI classnames (components, modifiers and responsive class names. Not colors)
    logs: true, // Shows info about daisyUI version and used config in the console when building your CSS
  },
}
```

[I was hoping this navbar would look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT431.png)

Comment: Just a few days ago I used daisyui with astro, everything worked but can't use custom colors just like yours

Comment: some key info would help, like, if you are using a framework? and it looks styles are actually not being applied. can you check the devtools and see if the stylesheet is actually there as well?